# xparse: Starred commands and \IfBooleanTF

Tags: xparse

In some longer redefinition of existing code I am using a construct like

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}


\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\mymacro}{smO{}m}{
    \def\blabla{#1}%
    % several lines later in another macro I use
    \IfBooleanTF{\blabla}{}{}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \mymacro*{}{}
\end{document}
```

which works fine with texlive 2018 (xparse 2018-10-17) and lualatex.
However, when trying with texlive 2019 (xparse  2019-03-05), I get the following error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error:
                Invalid use \IfBooleanTF {\blabla }
l.15     \mymacro*{}{}
```

What would be the correct way of doing something like this with the new xparse version?

---

Here is my complete macro definition where the case above occurs: Basically, I am trying to remove the caption from subcaptions including the vertical space. To achieve this, I modified parts of the subcaption package. This works for TL2018 as mentioned above and yields the following output:

[image]

Please note that I was particularly looking for a minimal invasive solution with respect to the other code I have. To this end, I thought that just adding a `*` to the `\subcaptionbox` is very convenient.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse,graphicx,subcaption,mwe,float}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF}{mmm}
{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{#2}
    {
        \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} {#2} {#3}
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
% This code makes \subcaptionbox*{}{\includegraphics...} print no label and remove the vertical space

\makeatletter
\let\oldsubcaptionbox\subcaptionbox
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subcaptionbox}{smO{}m}{
    \def\subcaptionbox@skip@subcpation{#1}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#3}{%
            \oldsubcaptionbox*{#2}{#4}%
        }{%
            \oldsubcaptionbox*{#2}[#3]{#4}%
        }%
    }{%
        \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#3}{%
            \oldsubcaptionbox{#2}{#4}%
        }{%
            \oldsubcaptionbox{#2}[#3]{#4}%
        }%
    }{%
    }%
}

\long\def\caption@iiibox#1#2#3#4[#5]#6{%
    \begingroup
    #1*% set \caption@position
    \caption@iftop{%
        \endgroup
        \parbox[t]{#4}{%
            #1\relax
            \caption@setposition t%
            \vbox{\caption#2{#3}}%
            \captionbox@hrule
            \csname caption@hj@#5\endcsname
            #6}%
    }{%
        \endgroup
        \parbox[b]{#4}{%
            #1\relax
            \caption@setposition b%
            \csname caption@hj@#5\endcsname
            #6%
            \captionbox@hrule%
            \IfBooleanTF{\subcaptionbox@skip@subcpation}{%
                \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#3}{}{%
                    \vtop{\caption#2{#3}}%
                }%
            }{%
                \vtop{\caption#2{#3}}%
            }%
        }%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}}%
    \end{figure}
    Blabla
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \subcaptionbox*{}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
        \subcaptionbox*{}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \end{figure}
    BlaBla
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why were you saving the argument in a macro in the first place?

Comment: @JosephWright I later redefine another macro where I use `\blabla`. I did not know another way of doing something like this.

Comment: @JosephWright, I added my full macro as requested by Kurt. I thought it was a fundamental thing within xparse that changed... Should I now change the title of the question as it may now look like I am more interesting in achieving the objective of removing the subcaption/vertical space?

Comment: The usage of `\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF` doesn't make sense. If you use `O{}` there is no possibility for the `-NoValue-` flag, because it defaults to be empty. Also using `\expandafter\IfBooleanTF\expandafter{\subcaptionbox@skip@subcpation}` should work (untested).

Comment: @Skillmon, thanks! That does it! However, please note that `O{}` is passed to to test (what is tested comes from the other macro)

Comment: @bonanza using `o` as argument specifier and then `\IfNoValueTF{#3}{\oldsubcaptionbox{#2}{#4}}{\oldsubcaptionbox{#2}[#3]{#4}}` in the code should work, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making your life difficult. If there is `*` and the argument is empty, just issue the last argument, possibly inside a box of the specified width.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse,graphicx,subcaption}

\let\oldsubcaptionbox\subcaptionbox

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfEmptyTF}{mmm}
 {
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\RenewDocumentCommand{\subcaptionbox}{smom}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {%
     \IfEmptyTF{#2}
      {#4}
      {\IfNoValueTF{#3}{\oldsubcaptionbox*{#2}{#4}}{\oldsubcaptionbox*{#2}[#3]{#4}}}%
    }
    {%
     \IfNoValueTF{#3}{\oldsubcaptionbox{#2}{#4}}{\oldsubcaptionbox{#2}[#3]{#4}}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp!]

\subcaptionbox{zzz}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
\subcaptionbox{zzz}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

\end{figure}

Blabla

\begin{figure}[htp!]

\subcaptionbox*{zzz}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
\subcaptionbox*{zzz}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

\end{figure}

Blabla

\begin{figure}[htp!]

\subcaptionbox*{}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
\subcaptionbox*{}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

\end{figure}

BlaBla

\end{document}
```

[image]